# Digital Mind insertion of points

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to put this code in the module =

```vb
Public pontosw (,) As = {{7, 8, 9, 5}}
```

but the variable I am not able to find when I insert the points in the form is missing in the code I put this

```vb
pontosw (ComboBoxNivel.SelectedIndex - 1, account - 1)
```

and this error appears

> Expression is not a method.

I have tried

```vb
Public pontosw (,) As Bolean = {{7, 8, 9, 5}} 
'or 
Public pontosw (,) As object = {{7, 8, 9, 5}}
```

Please explain to me which variable or method

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the right type in your question. It should be Integer

```vb
Dim pontosw As Integer(,) = {{7, 8, 9, 5}}
```

but sometimes it's easier to let the compiler decide implicitly. It's obviously integer

```vb
Dim pontosw = {{7, 8, 9, 5}}
```

You can access some specific index in the array, provided it exists

```vb
Dim a = pontosw(ComboBoxNivel.SelectedIndex - 1, account - 1)
```

According to what you've put in it, only indexing it with `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(0,2)`, `(0,3)` will work. This means `ComboBoxNivel.SelectedIndex` must equal 1, and `account` must be in the set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

[image]